# how to retrieve and pass data from more than 1 Schema in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

im newbie in expressjs and wondering how to retrieve and pass data from more than 1 schema in my controller.

here is the case, pretend i wanna open add_new_blog page and below is
the router;

```
router.get('/add_new_blog', BlogController.index);
```

well then in BlogController.index i need to retrieve Category and Tag Models.

```
const Category = require('models/categorySchema');
const Tag = require('models/tagSchema');

module.exports = {

  index(req, res, next){

    Category.find({});
    Tag.find({});

    // how to find/retrieve data from both Schema then i pass them to Views.


    res.render('/blog/blogForm');
  }
}
```

The Question is What the coding will look like to retrieve the data from both then pass it to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), get the two mongoose calls data and then render it.

```
const categoryFind = Category.find({}).exec(); // exec() returns a Promise.
const tagsFind = Tags.find({}).exec();

Promise.all(categoryFind, tagsFind).then((values) => {
  res.render('/blog/blogForm', { categories: values[0], tags: values[1] });
});
```

Notice that I render inside the callback, that is because mongoose calls are asynchronous. Otherwise you will be rendering before the queries have completed.

That is the same as:

```
Category.find({}, (err, catData) => {
  Tags.find({}, (err, tagsData) => {
    res.render('/blog/blogForm', { categories: catsData, tags: tagsData });
  }
}
```

Comment: it works! thank you sir.. is this the best practice or not sir?

Comment: @GoodDay it is the first one. The second example could lead to callback hell. http://callbackhell.com/